# Iterating map in C++ containing class objects

Tags: c++, stl

I am creating a map in C++ which contains a integer key and the value is an object of class User. I am able to insert the object into the map with the following code -

```
std::map<std::string,User>::iterator it = usermap.begin();
        usermap.insert (it, std::pair<string,User>(object.userid,object));
```

The code I am using to write the objects in a .bin file is -

```
map<std::string, User>::iterator it;
for ( it = usermap.begin(); it != usermap.end(); it++ )
{
myfile2 << "Object:" << it->second << "\n";
}
```

But the error I am getting when I am trying to run the code is -

**In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39:0,
                 from a3part2_5.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:548:5: note: template std::basic_ostream& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream&, const unsigned char*)
     operator<<(basic_ostream& __out, const unsigned char* __s)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:548:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
a3part2_5.cpp:90:31: note:   cannot convert ‘it.std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Tp>::operator->, User> >()->std::pair, User>::second’ (type ‘User’) to type ‘const unsigned char*’
  myfile2 << "Obejct: " << it->second << "\n";**

Any solutions for resolving the error?

My User class is defined as -

```
class User 
{ 
public: 
string userid; string uid; string gid; string gecos; string directory; string shell; 
User() {} 
};
```

Comment: Does your `User` class have an overloaded `operator <<` that you are trying to call?

Comment: I am pretty sure it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`User` is user-defined class and hence `ostream` cannot understand your `User` objects when you do `myfile2 << "Object:" << it->second << "\n";`

This should help [Overloading the << Operator for Your Own Classes.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx)

So you should overload `operator <<` for your class.

Comment: I tried looking at what you said and added the following code in my User class - 
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const User& user)
    {
        stream << user;
        return stream;
    }
Now I am getting a Bus error when I am trying to run the code.

Comment: `ostream` cannot understand `user` object as a whole. It understands fundamental types like `char, int, float` and some user-defined types (like `string`) for which its overloaded. After receiving `user` in the function you should do `stream << user.userid << ", " << user.uid;` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

An example:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream &os, User const& u){
    os << "userid:\t" u.userid << "\n";
    // ...
    return os;
}
```